# Adjoint problem to linear PDE system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, adjoint-operators, adjoint-functors, linear-pde

I am facing an issue with the adjoint system.

I have this PDE system, which is considered as strctured by $a$

\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \lambda P + \frac{\partial (\Gamma_0 P)}{\partial a}  + \frac{\partial (\Gamma_1(a,x) P) }{\partial x} = -(L(a,x) + F(a,x) + d_1) P + \tilde{G}Q,\\
    (\lambda + \tilde{G} + d_2)Q = L(a,x) P,\\
     P(0,x) = \frac{2}{\Gamma_0} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty f(a,x,y) \, P(a,y) \, da \, dy.
    \end{cases}
    \label{Lösungsmodell nach t}
\end{align}

and I have to get the adjoint system, which should look like that:

\begin{align}
    \begin{cases}
    \lambda \phi - \Gamma_0 \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial a}  - \Gamma_1(a,x) \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} - 2 \int_0^\infty \phi(0,y) f(a,y,x) \, da \, dy. \\ = -(L(a,x) + F(a,x) + d_1) \phi + L(a,x) \psi,\\
    (\lambda + \tilde{G} + d_2)\psi = \tilde{G}_\phi 
    \end{cases}
\end{align}

where they say it was normalised by this condition here:

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty}(\phi(a,x)P(a,x)+\psi(a,x)Q(a,x))\,da\,dx=1
\end{align}

I know that this is a really specific question but I am hoping for any answers.
I don't understand how to get the adjoint system and also how to use this normalisation condition.

Looking forward to any suggestions.
Thanks :)